# Typescript mixin constrained to typeof class

Tags: typescript

I was following this example from the [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html):

```
class Sprite {
  name = "";
  x = 0;
  y = 0;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

type GConstructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

type Spritable = GConstructor<typeof Sprite>;
```

Next, implemented a function that generates a class extending this type like this:

```
function Example<TBase extends Spritable>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Example extends Base {
    hello() {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  };
}
```

I assumed that I would then utilise this Mixin like this:

```
const x = Example(Sprite);
```

However, this throws the error

```
Argument of type 'typeof Sprite' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Spritable'.
```

If I modify the param passed into the generic constructor to be `type Spritable = GConstructor<Sprite>;`, the above code works.

However, in the typescript docs it's implemented using `typeof` which throws me an error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a mistake in the documentation. The generic parameter `T` is the return type of the constructor, so it should be the object type `Sprite` rather than the class type `typeof Sprite`.

I've submitted a PR to fix it: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/pull/1862

**Update:** The PR has been merged and the [Constrained-mixins documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins) now uses `GConstructor<Sprite>` istead of `GConstructor<typeof Sprite>`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was sure it must have been a typo but I thought perhaps there was some pattern I was unfamiliar with